# AWS Glue crawler is not seeing materialised views on Postgres

Tags: postgresql, oracle, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am using glue crawlers to introspect shemas and work with dataframes in glue. For oracle db connection crawler processes/adds tables, materialised views and regular views to AWS DB tables list, but for Postgres crawler only adds tables and does not add materialised views.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this?

Comment: on my case , the only way was convert the vist to a table and migrate using  dms service (very ugly but works)

Comment: @Alex5207 i dont remember tbh, tried finding how i made it work in my old code, but didn't, dont have access to AWS to check.

Comment: Thx for trying! @EdemSeithalilov. What I did was just to rebuild the materialized view inside glue using the source table